# Site loading extremely slowly

Tags: performance

I have a new website and it's loading extremely slowly. It happens both in admin area and frontend, so I'm guessing is not a plugin or theme issue. In fact, I've tried deactivating all plugins and activating one by one and found no difference. I've tried switching the theme too and it didn't solve the problem.

I have already contacted my hosting company and they told me there is nothing wrong with the server.

The website is http://www.marylindemuth.com.br

Do you have any idea of what might be going on? I have another website running in the same server and there are no issues with it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well I looked at the website using FireFox I hit F12 and went to the Network tab. Hit the refresh button within the tab.  This is the result I got a bunch of your CSS and images are taking a really long time to load.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor#Performance_analysis

[image: My Results]

Comment: Hello, EJD. Thanks for your time. I really think there is a problem with my hosting server. I ran some tests in Pingdom and it showed me a lot of "The web browser is waiting for data from the server". I've already contacted the company and it seems that they're doing something about it, since the website is loading super fast now and I didn't change anything.

Comment: @GiovannaCóppola I agree it's your host.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your website through [pingdom](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/cScMwk/http://www.marylindemuth.com.br) and [gtmetrix](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.marylindemuth.com.br/S7SGgl4N). Neither of them are showing extreme slowness - so far, as I repeat a few times, I'm getting variance between 3 and 6 seconds. Your website loads quickly enough for me in my browser. Have you changed something since you made this post?

Do you notice the same speed issues when you open an incognito browser window and you're not logged in to wp-admin?

Comment: Pranada, thanks for your time. I contacted my hosting company again. They didn't reply yet, but maybe they're doing something about it already. I didn't change anything and now the website is loading very quickly for me too.

Comment: I'm glad it's better for you - but it's still concerning to hear that it was inexplicably slow! Do you have cpanel access or another way to get at the stats for your server and see if your resource usage was spiking for some reason? And are you on shared hosting?